# Forecasting for multiple items

Tags: r, batch-processing

I have weekly data set for multiple servers from Dec 2015 to Feb 2018.
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lsXZ.png)

```
DATE    Server Name PERCENT_USED
11/11/2016  XXXKC   47.1
11/11/2016  XXXKD   38.79
11/11/2016  XXXMC   57.63
11/11/2016  XXXMD   62.84
11/11/2016  XXXTC   32.16
11/11/2016  XXXTD   27.32
11/11/2016  XXXOC   56.88
11/11/2016  XXXOD   38.06
11/11/2016  XXXLC   58.56
11/11/2016  XXXLD   53.86
11/11/2016  XXXLF   33.17
11/11/2016  XXXUC   47.4
11/11/2016  XXXUD   60.82
11/11/2016  XXXUF   78.06
11/11/2016  XXXPC   59.43
11/11/2016  XXXPD   50.68
11/11/2016  XXXPF   28.38
11/11/2016  XXXWC   68.87
11/11/2016  XXXWD   38.82
11/11/2016  XXXWF   37.61
11/11/2016  XXXHC   56.63
11/11/2016  XXXHD   64.96
11/11/2016  XXXIC   72.79
11/11/2016  XXXID   47.1
11/11/2016  XXXJC   59.6
11/11/2016  XXXJD   19.76
11/11/2016  XXXQC   65.61
11/11/2016  XXXQD   54.22
11/18/2016  XXXKC   47.17
11/18/2016  XXXKD   41.29
11/18/2016  XXXMC   58.24
11/18/2016  XXXMD   62.84
11/18/2016  XXXTC   32.2
11/18/2016  XXXTD   27.42
11/18/2016  XXXOC   56.97
11/18/2016  XXXOD   38.06
11/18/2016  XXXLC   58.01
11/18/2016  XXXLD   54.46
11/18/2016  XXXLF   33.5
11/18/2016  XXXUC   47.43
11/18/2016  XXXUD   60.73
11/18/2016  XXXUF   78.41
11/18/2016  XXXPC   58.84
11/18/2016  XXXPD   50.67
11/18/2016  XXXPF   28.36
11/18/2016  XXXWC   68.8
11/18/2016  XXXWD   39.42
11/18/2016  XXXWF   38.02
11/18/2016  XXXHC   56.93
11/18/2016  XXXHD   64.94
11/18/2016  XXXIC   72.72
11/18/2016  XXXID   47.42
11/18/2016  XXXJD   20.45
11/18/2016  XXXJC   59.69
11/18/2016  XXXQC   65.73
11/18/2016  XXXQD   57.81
11/25/2016  XXXKC   47.5
11/25/2016  XXXKD   36.27
11/25/2016  XXXMC   58.07
11/25/2016  XXXMD   62.93
11/25/2016  XXXTC   31.19
11/25/2016  XXXTD   27.4
11/25/2016  XXXOC   57.95
11/25/2016  XXXOD   38.12
11/25/2016  XXXLC   57.66
11/25/2016  XXXLD   54.86
11/25/2016  XXXLF   33.93
11/25/2016  XXXUC   47.1
11/25/2016  XXXUD   56.73
11/25/2016  XXXUF   78.83
11/25/2016  XXXPC   58.8
11/25/2016  XXXPD   51.29
11/25/2016  XXXPF   29.51
11/25/2016  XXXWC   68.52
11/25/2016  XXXWD   39.76
11/25/2016  XXXWF   38.68
11/25/2016  XXXHC   57.89
11/25/2016  XXXHD   65.34
11/25/2016  XXXIC   73.13
11/25/2016  XXXID   47.43
11/25/2016  XXXJC   59.99
11/25/2016  XXXJD   18.51
11/25/2016  XXXQC   65.5
11/25/2016  XXXQD   47.02
12/2/2016   XXXKC   47.42
12/2/2016   XXXKD   37.18
12/2/2016   XXXMC   57.98
12/2/2016   XXXMD   63.02
12/2/2016   XXXTC   30.82
12/2/2016   XXXTD   27.39
12/2/2016   XXXOD   38.26
12/2/2016   XXXOC   58.06
12/2/2016   XXXLC   57.69
12/2/2016   XXXLD   55.14
12/2/2016   XXXLF   34.19
12/2/2016   XXXUC   47.05
12/2/2016   XXXUD   53.88
12/2/2016   XXXUF   79.27
12/2/2016   XXXPC   58.83
12/2/2016   XXXPD   51.62
12/2/2016   XXXPF   30.5
12/2/2016   XXXWC   68.47
12/2/2016   XXXWD   40.05
12/2/2016   XXXWF   39.65
12/2/2016   XXXHC   57.71
12/2/2016   XXXHD   65.62
12/2/2016   XXXIC   72.74
12/2/2016   XXXID   47.27
12/2/2016   XXXJC   60.1
12/2/2016   XXXJD   18.8
12/2/2016   XXXQC   65.62
12/2/2016   XXXQD   48.13
12/9/2016   XXXKC   47.44
12/9/2016   XXXKD   41.14
12/9/2016   XXXMC   58.03
12/9/2016   XXXMD   63.06
12/9/2016   XXXTC   31.07
12/9/2016   XXXTD   27.45
12/9/2016   XXXOC   57.24
12/9/2016   XXXOD   38.4
12/9/2016   XXXLC   57.76
12/9/2016   XXXLD   55.81
12/9/2016   XXXLF   34.48
12/9/2016   XXXUC   47.04
12/9/2016   XXXUD   53.66
12/9/2016   XXXUF   79.64
12/9/2016   XXXPC   58.88
12/9/2016   XXXPD   51.57
12/9/2016   XXXPF   30.51
12/9/2016   XXXWC   68.34
12/9/2016   XXXWD   40.76
12/9/2016   XXXWF   40.02
12/9/2016   XXXHC   57.73
12/9/2016   XXXHD   65.81
12/9/2016   XXXIC   72.76
12/9/2016   XXXID   47.03
12/9/2016   XXXJC   60.11
12/9/2016   XXXJD   20.16
12/9/2016   XXXQC   65.99
12/9/2016   XXXQD   52.02
12/16/2016  XXXKC   47.51
12/16/2016  XXXKD   40.61
12/16/2016  XXXMC   58.16
12/16/2016  XXXMD   63.4
12/16/2016  XXXTC   31.64
12/16/2016  XXXTD   27.48
12/16/2016  XXXOC   57.37
12/16/2016  XXXOD   39.45
12/16/2016  XXXLC   57.94
12/16/2016  XXXLD   56.79
12/16/2016  XXXLF   35.03
12/16/2016  XXXUC   47.07
12/16/2016  XXXUD   53.55
12/16/2016  XXXUF   80.13
12/16/2016  XXXPC   58.82
12/16/2016  XXXPD   51.63
12/16/2016  XXXPF   31.58
12/16/2016  XXXWC   68.44
12/16/2016  XXXWD   41.75
12/16/2016  XXXWF   40.41
12/16/2016  XXXHC   57.9
12/16/2016  XXXHD   65.92
12/16/2016  XXXIC   72.91
12/16/2016  XXXID   47.67
12/16/2016  XXXJC   60.59
12/16/2016  XXXJD   20.1
12/16/2016  XXXQC   66.18
12/16/2016  XXXQD   51.47
12/23/2016  XXXKC   47.57
12/23/2016  XXXKD   40.25
12/23/2016  XXXMC   58.16
12/23/2016  XXXMD   63.43
12/23/2016  XXXTC   31.77
12/23/2016  XXXTD   27.49
12/23/2016  XXXOC   57.31
12/23/2016  XXXOD   39.6
12/23/2016  XXXLC   57.87
12/23/2016  XXXLD   57.23
12/23/2016  XXXLF   35.28
12/23/2016  XXXUC   46.98
12/23/2016  XXXUD   53.36
12/23/2016  XXXUF   80.24
12/23/2016  XXXPC   58.85
12/23/2016  XXXPD   51.63
12/23/2016  XXXPF   31.17
12/23/2016  XXXWC   68.5
12/23/2016  XXXWD   42.17
12/23/2016  XXXWF   39.85
12/23/2016  XXXHC   57.97
12/23/2016  XXXHD   66.04
12/23/2016  XXXIC   73.19
12/23/2016  XXXID   47.64
12/23/2016  XXXJC   60.52
12/23/2016  XXXJD   19.89
12/23/2016  XXXQC   66.44
12/23/2016  XXXQD   51.24
12/30/2016  XXXKC   47.57
12/30/2016  XXXKD   38.95
12/30/2016  XXXMC   58.16
12/30/2016  XXXMD   63.47
12/30/2016  XXXTC   32.03
12/30/2016  XXXTD   27.52
12/30/2016  XXXOC   57.73
12/30/2016  XXXOD   39.74
12/30/2016  XXXLC   57.86
12/30/2016  XXXLD   57.75
12/30/2016  XXXLF   35.64
12/30/2016  XXXUC   47.06
12/30/2016  XXXUD   53.08
12/30/2016  XXXUF   80.78
12/30/2016  XXXPC   58.89
12/30/2016  XXXPD   51.63
12/30/2016  XXXPF   32.48
12/30/2016  XXXWC   68.56
12/30/2016  XXXWD   42.64
12/30/2016  XXXWF   41.03
12/30/2016  XXXHC   64.4
12/30/2016  XXXHD   66.04
12/30/2016  XXXIC   80.69
12/30/2016  XXXID   47.13
12/30/2016  XXXJC   60.54
12/30/2016  XXXJD   19.41
12/30/2016  XXXQC   67.18
12/30/2016  XXXQD   50.11
1/6/2017    XXXKC   47.6
1/6/2017    XXXKD   39.88
1/6/2017    XXXMC   58.14
1/6/2017    XXXMD   65.77
1/6/2017    XXXTC   31.37
1/6/2017    XXXTD   27.48
1/6/2017    XXXOC   58.67
1/6/2017    XXXOD   39.88
1/6/2017    XXXLC   57.9
1/6/2017    XXXLD   58.24
1/6/2017    XXXLF   35.89
1/6/2017    XXXUC   47.06
1/6/2017    XXXUD   52.88
1/6/2017    XXXUF   81.08
1/6/2017    XXXPC   58.91
1/6/2017    XXXPD   51.63
1/6/2017    XXXPF   32.2
1/6/2017    XXXWC   68.44
1/6/2017    XXXWD   43.18
1/6/2017    XXXWF   41.17
1/6/2017    XXXHC   64.78
1/6/2017    XXXHD   66.02
1/6/2017    XXXIC   80.76
1/6/2017    XXXID   47.14
1/6/2017    XXXJC   60.54
1/6/2017    XXXJD   19.77
1/6/2017    XXXQC   67.47
1/6/2017    XXXQD   50.99
1/13/2017   XXXKC   47.64
1/13/2017   XXXKD   37.71
1/13/2017   XXXMC   57.53
1/13/2017   XXXMD   65.84
1/13/2017   XXXTC   31.73
1/13/2017   XXXTD   27.51
1/13/2017   XXXOC   58.54
1/13/2017   XXXOD   40.07
1/13/2017   XXXLC   57.95
1/13/2017   XXXLD   58.52
1/13/2017   XXXLF   36.27
1/13/2017   XXXUC   47.02
1/13/2017   XXXUD   53.95
1/13/2017   XXXUF   81.37
1/13/2017   XXXPC   58.95
1/13/2017   XXXPD   52.05
1/13/2017   XXXPF   32.66
1/13/2017   XXXWC   68.48
1/13/2017   XXXWD   43.45
1/13/2017   XXXWF   41.07
1/13/2017   XXXHC   64.65
1/13/2017   XXXHD   65.76
1/13/2017   XXXIC   80.8
1/13/2017   XXXID   46.78
1/13/2017   XXXJC   60.75
1/13/2017   XXXJD   19.03
1/13/2017   XXXQC   67.55
1/13/2017   XXXQD   48.71
1/20/2017   XXXKC   47.54
1/20/2017   XXXKD   35.8
1/20/2017   XXXMC   57.55
1/20/2017   XXXMD   65.88
1/20/2017   XXXTC   32.04
1/20/2017   XXXTD   27.53
1/20/2017   XXXOC   58.57
1/20/2017   XXXOD   40.2
1/20/2017   XXXLC   57.99
1/20/2017   XXXLD   58.52
1/20/2017   XXXLF   36.6
1/20/2017   XXXUC   47.12
1/20/2017   XXXUD   55.48
1/20/2017   XXXUF   81.85
1/20/2017   XXXPC   58.83
1/20/2017   XXXPD   52.64
1/20/2017   XXXPF   33.54
1/20/2017   XXXWC   68.52
1/20/2017   XXXWD   43.46
1/20/2017   XXXWF   42.56
1/20/2017   XXXHC   64.68
1/20/2017   XXXHD   66.1
1/20/2017   XXXIC   80.8
1/20/2017   XXXID   47.05
1/20/2017   XXXJC   61
1/20/2017   XXXJD   18.56
1/20/2017   XXXQC   67.6
1/20/2017   XXXQD   46.77
1/27/2017   XXXKC   47.57
1/27/2017   XXXKD   37.19
1/27/2017   XXXMC   57.63
1/27/2017   XXXMD   65.92
1/27/2017   XXXTC   32.51
1/27/2017   XXXTD   27.48
1/27/2017   XXXOC   57.61
1/27/2017   XXXOD   40.36
1/27/2017   XXXLC   57.87
1/27/2017   XXXLD   58.82
1/27/2017   XXXLF   37
1/27/2017   XXXUC   47.02
1/27/2017   XXXUD   56.9
1/27/2017   XXXUF   82.07
1/27/2017   XXXPC   58.89
1/27/2017   XXXPD   53.2
1/27/2017   XXXPF   31.36
1/27/2017   XXXWC   68.6
1/27/2017   XXXWD   43.71
1/27/2017   XXXWF   41.83
1/27/2017   XXXHC   64.57
1/27/2017   XXXHD   65.89
1/27/2017   XXXIC   77.53
1/27/2017   XXXID   47.09
1/27/2017   XXXJC   61.08
1/27/2017   XXXJD   19.13
1/27/2017   XXXQC   67.69
1/27/2017   XXXQD   48.29
2/3/2017    XXXKC   47.6
2/3/2017    XXXKD   39.7
2/3/2017    XXXMC   57.72
2/3/2017    XXXMD   65.95
2/3/2017    XXXTC   32.73
2/3/2017    XXXTD   27.51
2/3/2017    XXXOC   57.46
2/3/2017    XXXOD   40.54
2/3/2017    XXXLC   57.91
2/3/2017    XXXLD   59.23
2/3/2017    XXXLF   37.29
2/3/2017    XXXUC   47.09
2/3/2017    XXXUD   57.46
2/3/2017    XXXUF   82.46
2/3/2017    XXXPC   58.93
2/3/2017    XXXPD   53.46
2/3/2017    XXXPF   32.45
2/3/2017    XXXWC   68.49
2/3/2017    XXXWD   44.18
2/3/2017    XXXWF   42.52
2/3/2017    XXXHC   64.59
2/3/2017    XXXHD   66.92
2/3/2017    XXXIC   76.34
2/3/2017    XXXID   47.87
2/3/2017    XXXJC   61.13
2/3/2017    XXXJD   20.71
2/3/2017    XXXQC   67.93
2/3/2017    XXXQD   50.87
2/10/2017   XXXKC   47.81
2/10/2017   XXXKD   43.13
2/10/2017   XXXMC   57.79
2/10/2017   XXXMD   66
2/10/2017   XXXTC   33.13
2/10/2017   XXXTD   27.53
2/10/2017   XXXOC   57.55
2/10/2017   XXXOD   40.71
2/10/2017   XXXLC   57.97
2/10/2017   XXXLD   58.67
2/10/2017   XXXLF   37.64
2/10/2017   XXXUC   47.06
2/10/2017   XXXUD   57.56
2/10/2017   XXXUF   82.73
2/10/2017   XXXPC   58.98
2/10/2017   XXXPD   53.42
2/10/2017   XXXPF   32.96
2/10/2017   XXXWC   68.55
2/10/2017   XXXWD   44.96
2/10/2017   XXXWF   43.42
2/10/2017   XXXHC   64.86
2/10/2017   XXXHD   69.87
2/10/2017   XXXIC   76.5
2/10/2017   XXXID   52.63
2/10/2017   XXXJC   61.31
2/10/2017   XXXJD   21.18
2/10/2017   XXXQC   68.53
2/10/2017   XXXQD   54.17
2/17/2017   XXXKC   47.84
2/17/2017   XXXKD   40.68
2/17/2017   XXXMC   57.98
2/17/2017   XXXMD   66.05
2/17/2017   XXXTC   33.54
2/17/2017   XXXTD   27.46
2/17/2017   XXXOC   57.77
2/17/2017   XXXOD   40.94
2/17/2017   XXXLC   58.32
2/17/2017   XXXLD   57.23
2/17/2017   XXXLF   37.98
2/17/2017   XXXUC   47.29
2/17/2017   XXXUD   58.85
2/17/2017   XXXUF   82.93
2/17/2017   XXXPC   59.01
2/17/2017   XXXPD   54.65
2/17/2017   XXXPF   33.71
2/17/2017   XXXWC   68.6
2/17/2017   XXXWD   48.61
2/17/2017   XXXWF   42.34
2/17/2017   XXXHC   64.9
2/17/2017   XXXHD   70.33
2/17/2017   XXXIC   76.52
2/17/2017   XXXID   52.71
2/17/2017   XXXJC   61.25
2/17/2017   XXXJD   20.29
2/17/2017   XXXQC   68.57
2/17/2017   XXXQD   51.52
2/24/2017   XXXKC   47.84
2/24/2017   XXXKD   41.52
2/24/2017   XXXMC   58.65
2/24/2017   XXXMD   66
2/24/2017   XXXTC   34.23
2/24/2017   XXXTD   27.47
2/24/2017   XXXOC   58.45
2/24/2017   XXXOD   41.05
2/24/2017   XXXLC   58.59
2/24/2017   XXXLD   59.54
2/24/2017   XXXLF   38.36
2/24/2017   XXXUC   47.69
2/24/2017   XXXUD   59.62
2/24/2017   XXXUF   83.33
2/24/2017   XXXPC   58.93
2/24/2017   XXXPD   55.81
2/24/2017   XXXPF   33.98
2/24/2017   XXXWC   68.49
2/24/2017   XXXWD   50.97
2/24/2017   XXXWF   42.7
2/24/2017   XXXHC   64.81
2/24/2017   XXXHD   70.44
2/24/2017   XXXIC   76.47
2/24/2017   XXXID   52.7
2/24/2017   XXXJC   61.32
2/24/2017   XXXJD   20.8
2/24/2017   XXXQC   68.78
2/24/2017   XXXQD   51.97
3/3/2017    XXXKC   45.54
3/3/2017    XXXKD   43.01
3/3/2017    XXXMC   58.71
3/3/2017    XXXMD   65.95
3/3/2017    XXXTC   32.28
3/3/2017    XXXTD   27.46
3/3/2017    XXXOC   58.39
3/3/2017    XXXOD   41.07
3/3/2017    XXXLC   58.48
3/3/2017    XXXLD   60.42
3/3/2017    XXXLF   38.75
3/3/2017    XXXUC   46.53
3/3/2017    XXXUD   59.58
3/3/2017    XXXUF   47.64
3/3/2017    XXXPC   58.98
3/3/2017    XXXPD   55.8
3/3/2017    XXXPF   34.75
3/3/2017    XXXWC   68.54
3/3/2017    XXXWD   51.84
3/3/2017    XXXWF   42.95
3/3/2017    XXXHC   63.91
3/3/2017    XXXHD   70.28
3/3/2017    XXXIC   71.67
3/3/2017    XXXID   53
3/3/2017    XXXJC   59.58
3/3/2017    XXXJD   21.27
3/3/2017    XXXQC   66.89
3/3/2017    XXXQD   53.54
3/10/2017   XXXKC   45.74
3/10/2017   XXXKD   40.01
3/10/2017   XXXMC   58.5
3/10/2017   XXXMD   65.96
3/10/2017   XXXTC   32.1
3/10/2017   XXXTD   27.47
3/10/2017   XXXOC   58.23
3/10/2017   XXXOD   41.06
3/10/2017   XXXLC   58.51
3/10/2017   XXXLD   60.82
3/10/2017   XXXLF   39.02
3/10/2017   XXXUC   45.64
3/10/2017   XXXUD   60.5
3/10/2017   XXXUF   18.67
3/10/2017   XXXPC   58.99
3/10/2017   XXXPD   56.2
3/10/2017   XXXPF   34.98
3/10/2017   XXXWC   68.56
3/10/2017   XXXWD   52.17
3/10/2017   XXXWF   43.61
3/10/2017   XXXHC   63.73
3/10/2017   XXXHD   70.1
3/10/2017   XXXIC   63.92
3/10/2017   XXXID   52.44
3/10/2017   XXXJC   59.51
3/10/2017   XXXJD   20.28
3/10/2017   XXXQC   66.51
3/10/2017   XXXQD   50.61
3/17/2017   XXXKC   45.82
3/17/2017   XXXKD   36.15
3/17/2017   XXXMC   58.34
3/17/2017   XXXMD   65.95
3/17/2017   XXXTC   32.4
3/17/2017   XXXTD   27.46
3/17/2017   XXXOC   58.4
3/17/2017   XXXOD   41.08
3/17/2017   XXXLC   58.59
3/17/2017   XXXLD   60.82
3/17/2017   XXXLF   39.33
3/17/2017   XXXUC   46.05
3/17/2017   XXXUD   62.07
3/17/2017   XXXUF   19.08
3/17/2017   XXXPC   59.05
3/17/2017   XXXPD   56.86
3/17/2017   XXXPF   35.42
3/17/2017   XXXWC   68.27
3/17/2017   XXXWD   52.17
3/17/2017   XXXWF   44.13
3/17/2017   XXXHC   63.65
3/17/2017   XXXHD   67.46
3/17/2017   XXXIC   63.84
3/17/2017   XXXID   52.54
3/17/2017   XXXJC   59.45
3/17/2017   XXXJD   18.98
3/17/2017   XXXQC   66.43
3/17/2017   XXXQD   46.75
3/24/2017   XXXKC   45.84
3/24/2017   XXXKD   36.97
3/24/2017   XXXMC   58.37
3/24/2017   XXXMD   65.97
3/24/2017   XXXTC   31.77
3/24/2017   XXXTD   27.48
3/24/2017   XXXOC   58.49
3/24/2017   XXXOD   41.1
3/24/2017   XXXLC   58.84
3/24/2017   XXXLD   60.86
3/24/2017   XXXLF   39.75
3/24/2017   XXXUC   47.27
3/24/2017   XXXUD   63.74
3/24/2017   XXXUF   19.18
3/24/2017   XXXPC   59.1
3/24/2017   XXXPD   57.64
3/24/2017   XXXPF   34.9
3/24/2017   XXXWC   67.05
3/24/2017   XXXWD   52.31
3/24/2017   XXXWF   45.05
3/24/2017   XXXHC   63.49
3/24/2017   XXXHD   58.67
3/24/2017   XXXIC   63.49
3/24/2017   XXXID   52.8
3/24/2017   XXXJC   59.54
3/24/2017   XXXJD   19.37
3/24/2017   XXXQC   66.43
3/24/2017   XXXQD   47.43
3/31/2017   XXXKC   45.52
3/31/2017   XXXKD   40.63
3/31/2017   XXXMC   57.46
3/31/2017   XXXMD   65.63
3/31/2017   XXXTC   49.87
3/31/2017   XXXTD   47.46
3/31/2017   XXXOC   62.73
3/31/2017   XXXOD   48.1
3/31/2017   XXXLC   58.91
3/31/2017   XXXLD   61.4
3/31/2017   XXXLF   40.24
3/31/2017   XXXUC   47.53
3/31/2017   XXXUD   64.54
3/31/2017   XXXUF   19.28
3/31/2017   XXXPC   59.15
3/31/2017   XXXPD   57.99
3/31/2017   XXXPF   35.94
3/31/2017   XXXWC   67.09
3/31/2017   XXXWD   52.83
3/31/2017   XXXWF   45.68
3/31/2017   XXXHC   63.83
3/31/2017   XXXHD   59.35
3/31/2017   XXXIC   63.9
3/31/2017   XXXID   51.78
3/31/2017   XXXJC   59.72
3/31/2017   XXXJD   20.79
3/31/2017   XXXQC   66.48
3/31/2017   XXXQD   51.39
4/7/2017    XXXKC   45.66
4/7/2017    XXXKD   39.29
4/7/2017    XXXMC   54.44
4/7/2017    XXXMD   60.52
4/7/2017    XXXTC   44.99
4/7/2017    XXXTD   73.83
4/7/2017    XXXOC   65.89
4/7/2017    XXXOD   54.43
4/7/2017    XXXLC   58.77
4/7/2017    XXXLD   61.71
4/7/2017    XXXLF   40.55
4/7/2017    XXXUC   47.54
4/7/2017    XXXUD   65.74
4/7/2017    XXXUF   19.62
4/7/2017    XXXPC   59.16
4/7/2017    XXXPD   58.52
4/7/2017    XXXPF   35.86
4/7/2017    XXXWC   67.14
4/7/2017    XXXWD   53.03
4/7/2017    XXXWF   44.35
4/7/2017    XXXHC   64.1
4/7/2017    XXXHD   61.37
4/7/2017    XXXIC   63.88
4/7/2017    XXXID   51.5
4/7/2017    XXXJC   59.92
4/7/2017    XXXJD   20.2
4/7/2017    XXXQC   66.59
4/7/2017    XXXQD   50.05
4/14/2017   XXXKC   45.62
4/14/2017   XXXKD   40.26
4/14/2017   XXXMC   54.49
4/14/2017   XXXMD   60.51
4/14/2017   XXXTC   37.99
4/14/2017   XXXTD   70.55
4/14/2017   XXXOC   65.92
4/14/2017   XXXOD   54.33
4/14/2017   XXXLC   58.84
4/14/2017   XXXLD   62.05
4/14/2017   XXXLF   40.82
4/14/2017   XXXUC   47.57
4/14/2017   XXXUD   66.18
4/14/2017   XXXUF   20.26
4/14/2017   XXXPC   59.19
4/14/2017   XXXPD   58.77
4/14/2017   XXXPF   36.46
4/14/2017   XXXWC   67.19
4/14/2017   XXXWD   53.38
4/14/2017   XXXWF   44.93
4/14/2017   XXXHC   64.08
4/14/2017   XXXHD   61.62
4/14/2017   XXXIC   63.92
4/14/2017   XXXID   51.76
4/14/2017   XXXJC   59.8
4/14/2017   XXXJD   20.82
4/14/2017   XXXQC   66.63
4/14/2017   XXXQD   50.89
4/21/2017   XXXKC   45.62
4/21/2017   XXXKD   45.72
4/21/2017   XXXMC   54.53
4/21/2017   XXXMD   60.47
4/21/2017   XXXTC   38.38
4/21/2017   XXXTD   70.56
4/21/2017   XXXOC   66.25
4/21/2017   XXXOD   54.24
4/21/2017   XXXLC   58.97
4/21/2017   XXXLD   64.58
4/21/2017   XXXLF   41.32
4/21/2017   XXXUC   47.83
4/21/2017   XXXUD   67.64
4/21/2017   XXXUF   20.83
4/21/2017   XXXPC   59.62
4/21/2017   XXXPD   61.98
4/21/2017   XXXPF   37.31
4/21/2017   XXXWC   67.08
4/21/2017   XXXWD   55.75
4/21/2017   XXXWF   45.76
4/21/2017   XXXHC   63.91
4/21/2017   XXXHD   61.59
4/21/2017   XXXIC   63.83
4/21/2017   XXXID   52.55
4/21/2017   XXXJC   60.78
4/21/2017   XXXJD   22.86
4/21/2017   XXXQC   67.87
4/21/2017   XXXQD   54.96
4/28/2017   XXXKC   45.72
4/28/2017   XXXKD   49.16
4/28/2017   XXXMC   54.57
4/28/2017   XXXMD   60.43
4/28/2017   XXXTC   38.08
4/28/2017   XXXTD   70.57
4/28/2017   XXXOC   66.31
4/28/2017   XXXOD   54.2
4/28/2017   XXXLC   59.05
4/28/2017   XXXLD   67.3
4/28/2017   XXXLF   41.61
4/28/2017   XXXUC   48.01
4/28/2017   XXXUD   69.86
4/28/2017   XXXUF   21.06
4/28/2017   XXXPC   59.87
4/28/2017   XXXPD   64.78
4/28/2017   XXXPF   37.66
4/28/2017   XXXWC   67.15
4/28/2017   XXXWD   58.13
4/28/2017   XXXWF   46
4/28/2017   XXXHC   63.8
4/28/2017   XXXHD   61.79
4/28/2017   XXXIC   63.9
4/28/2017   XXXID   52.6
4/28/2017   XXXJC   62.16
4/28/2017   XXXJD   24.25
4/28/2017   XXXQC   69.92
4/28/2017   XXXQD   53.71
5/5/2017    XXXKC   45.72
5/5/2017    XXXKD   47.29
5/5/2017    XXXMC   54.48
5/5/2017    XXXMD   60.44
5/5/2017    XXXTC   38.15
5/5/2017    XXXTD   70.58
5/5/2017    XXXOC   66.25
5/5/2017    XXXOD   54.21
5/5/2017    XXXLF   41.99
5/5/2017    XXXLC   58.92
5/5/2017    XXXLD   67.38
5/5/2017    XXXUC   48.02
5/5/2017    XXXUD   71.99
5/5/2017    XXXUF   21.34
5/5/2017    XXXPC   59.95
5/5/2017    XXXPD   65.81
5/5/2017    XXXPF   37.82
5/5/2017    XXXWC   67.2
5/5/2017    XXXWD   58.12
5/5/2017    XXXWF   46.28
5/5/2017    XXXHC   63.79
5/5/2017    XXXHD   62.15
5/5/2017    XXXIC   63.97
5/5/2017    XXXID   52.63
5/5/2017    XXXJC   61.94
5/5/2017    XXXJD   23.51
5/5/2017    XXXQC   70.13
5/5/2017    XXXQD   51.98
5/12/2017   XXXKC   45.72
5/12/2017   XXXKD   54.96
5/12/2017   XXXMC   54.51
5/12/2017   XXXMD   60.41
5/12/2017   XXXTC   38.34
5/12/2017   XXXTD   70.61
5/12/2017   XXXOC   66.5
5/12/2017   XXXOD   54.19
5/12/2017   XXXLC   58.99
5/12/2017   XXXLD   67.92
5/12/2017   XXXLF   42.29
5/12/2017   XXXUC   48.09
5/12/2017   XXXUD   72.54
5/12/2017   XXXUF   21.76
5/12/2017   XXXPF   37.18
5/12/2017   XXXPC   59.99
5/12/2017   XXXPD   66.08
5/12/2017   XXXWC   67.12
5/12/2017   XXXWD   58.72
5/12/2017   XXXWF   46.71
5/12/2017   XXXHC   63.82
5/12/2017   XXXHD   62.33
5/12/2017   XXXIC   63.93
5/12/2017   XXXID   52.66
5/12/2017   XXXJC   61.91
5/12/2017   XXXJD   26.08
5/12/2017   XXXQC   70.12
5/12/2017   XXXQD   58.74
5/19/2017   XXXKC   45.59
5/19/2017   XXXKD   59.36
5/19/2017   XXXMC   54.77
5/19/2017   XXXMD   60.36
5/19/2017   XXXTC   38.25
5/19/2017   XXXTD   70.58
5/19/2017   XXXOC   66.38
5/19/2017   XXXOD   54.15
5/19/2017   XXXLC   59.35
5/19/2017   XXXLD   68.6
5/19/2017   XXXLF   42.65
5/19/2017   XXXUC   48.05
5/19/2017   XXXUD   72.79
5/19/2017   XXXUF   21.99
5/19/2017   XXXPC   60.22
5/19/2017   XXXPD   66.26
5/19/2017   XXXPF   37.12
5/19/2017   XXXWC   67.18
5/19/2017   XXXWD   59.39
5/19/2017   XXXWF   46.86
5/19/2017   XXXHC   64.02
5/19/2017   XXXHD   62.67
5/19/2017   XXXIC   63.95
5/19/2017   XXXID   52.31
5/19/2017   XXXJC   62.02
5/19/2017   XXXJD   27.58
5/19/2017   XXXQC   70.1
5/19/2017   XXXQD   59.52
5/26/2017   XXXKC   45.54
5/26/2017   XXXKD   54.05
5/26/2017   XXXMC   54.9
5/26/2017   XXXMD   60.36
5/26/2017   XXXTC   37.81
5/26/2017   XXXTD   70.61
5/26/2017   XXXOC   66.53
5/26/2017   XXXOD   54.14
5/26/2017   XXXLC   59.44
5/26/2017   XXXLD   68.62
5/26/2017   XXXLF   42.99
5/26/2017   XXXUC   48.07
5/26/2017   XXXUD   74.24
5/26/2017   XXXUF   22.3
5/26/2017   XXXPC   60.28
5/26/2017   XXXPD   66.87
5/26/2017   XXXPF   37.48
5/26/2017   XXXWC   67.26
5/26/2017   XXXWD   59.37
5/26/2017   XXXWF   46.88
5/26/2017   XXXHC   64.56
5/26/2017   XXXHD   62.88
5/26/2017   XXXIC   64.42
5/26/2017   XXXID   52.02
5/26/2017   XXXJC   62.1
5/26/2017   XXXJD   25.74
5/26/2017   XXXQC   70.16
5/26/2017   XXXQD   53.8
6/2/2017    XXXKC   45.62
6/2/2017    XXXKD   54.14
6/2/2017    XXXMC   55
6/2/2017    XXXMD   60.36
6/2/2017    XXXTC   37.98
6/2/2017    XXXTD   70.58
6/2/2017    XXXOC   66.62
6/2/2017    XXXOD   54.11
6/2/2017    XXXLC   60.99
6/2/2017    XXXLD   69.72
6/2/2017    XXXLF   47.01
6/2/2017    XXXUC   49.03
6/2/2017    XXXUD   66.38
6/2/2017    XXXUF   26.44
6/2/2017    XXXPF   41.99
6/2/2017    XXXPC   61.07
6/2/2017    XXXPD   61.98
6/2/2017    XXXWC   68.52
6/2/2017    XXXWD   60.15
6/2/2017    XXXWF   52.87
6/2/2017    XXXHC   65.38
6/2/2017    XXXHD   63
6/2/2017    XXXIC   65.1
6/2/2017    XXXID   52.1
6/2/2017    XXXJC   62
6/2/2017    XXXJD   26.04
6/2/2017    XXXQC   70.22
6/2/2017    XXXQD   53.83
6/9/2017    XXXKC   45.66
6/9/2017    XXXKD   54.23
6/9/2017    XXXMC   55.06
6/9/2017    XXXMD   60.37
6/9/2017    XXXTC   38.09
6/9/2017    XXXTD   70.6
6/9/2017    XXXOC   66.65
6/9/2017    XXXOD   54.06
6/9/2017    XXXLC   63.02
6/9/2017    XXXLD   70.53
6/9/2017    XXXLF   52.47
6/9/2017    XXXUC   50.42
6/9/2017    XXXUD   50.93
6/9/2017    XXXUF   31.52
6/9/2017    XXXPC   62.73
6/9/2017    XXXPD   52.62
6/9/2017    XXXPF   47.97
6/9/2017    XXXWC   70.11
6/9/2017    XXXWD   61.28
6/9/2017    XXXWF   59.9
6/9/2017    XXXHC   65.45
6/9/2017    XXXHD   63.06
6/9/2017    XXXIC   65.11
6/9/2017    XXXID   52.16
6/9/2017    XXXJC   62.06
6/9/2017    XXXJD   25.64
6/9/2017    XXXQC   70.27
6/9/2017    XXXQD   53.97
6/16/2017   XXXKC   45.93
6/16/2017   XXXKD   58.06
6/16/2017   XXXMC   55.79
6/16/2017   XXXMD   60.36
6/16/2017   XXXTC   38.6
6/16/2017   XXXTD   70.65
6/16/2017   XXXOC   67.17
6/16/2017   XXXOD   54.1
6/16/2017   XXXLC   63.56
6/16/2017   XXXLD   71.13
6/16/2017   XXXLF   52.77
6/16/2017   XXXUC   50.66
6/16/2017   XXXUD   51.01
6/16/2017   XXXUF   31.77
6/16/2017   XXXPC   63.15
6/16/2017   XXXPD   52.78
6/16/2017   XXXPF   48.11
6/16/2017   XXXWC   70.68
6/16/2017   XXXWD   61.87
6/16/2017   XXXWF   59.24
6/16/2017   XXXHC   65.81
6/16/2017   XXXHD   63.03
6/16/2017   XXXIC   65.59
6/16/2017   XXXID   52.13
6/16/2017   XXXJC   62.73
6/16/2017   XXXJD   26.53
6/16/2017   XXXQC   70.66
6/16/2017   XXXQD   57.6
6/23/2017   XXXKD   58.38
6/23/2017   XXXKC   46.17
6/23/2017   XXXMC   56.16
6/23/2017   XXXMD   60.36
6/23/2017   XXXTC   39.32
6/23/2017   XXXTD   70.58
6/23/2017   XXXOC   67.73
6/23/2017   XXXOD   54.04
6/23/2017   XXXLC   64.48
6/23/2017   XXXLD   73.08
6/23/2017   XXXLF   53.15
6/23/2017   XXXUC   51.14
6/23/2017   XXXUD   50.79
6/23/2017   XXXUF   32.44
6/23/2017   XXXPC   63.95
6/23/2017   XXXPD   52.76
6/23/2017   XXXPF   48.94
6/23/2017   XXXWC   71.18
6/23/2017   XXXWD   62.59
6/23/2017   XXXWF   60.09
6/23/2017   XXXHC   66.07
6/23/2017   XXXHD   63.12
6/23/2017   XXXIC   65.91
6/23/2017   XXXID   52.14
6/23/2017   XXXJC   62.92
6/23/2017   XXXJD   26.52
6/23/2017   XXXQC   70.98
6/23/2017   XXXQD   58.08
6/30/2017   XXXKC   46.52
6/30/2017   XXXKD   57.82
6/30/2017   XXXMC   56.15
6/30/2017   XXXMD   54.31
6/30/2017   XXXTC   39.1
6/30/2017   XXXTD   58.28
6/30/2017   XXXOC   67.64
6/30/2017   XXXOD   47.24
6/30/2017   XXXLC   64.5
6/30/2017   XXXLD   81.65
6/30/2017   XXXLF   53.49
6/30/2017   XXXUC   51.49
6/30/2017   XXXUD   51.48
6/30/2017   XXXUF   32.62
6/30/2017   XXXPC   63.8
6/30/2017   XXXPD   53.19
6/30/2017   XXXPF   49.14
6/30/2017   XXXWC   71.81
6/30/2017   XXXWD   62.88
6/30/2017   XXXWF   60.3
6/30/2017   XXXHC   66.17
6/30/2017   XXXHD   63.03
6/30/2017   XXXIC   66.22
6/30/2017   XXXID   52.31
6/30/2017   XXXJC   63.26
6/30/2017   XXXJD   25.86
6/30/2017   XXXQC   71.26
6/30/2017   XXXQD   55.79
7/7/2017    XXXKC   46.35
7/7/2017    XXXKD   60.77
7/7/2017    XXXMD   38.21
7/7/2017    XXXMC   56.88
7/7/2017    XXXTC   38.99
7/7/2017    XXXTD   24.44
7/7/2017    XXXOC   67.37
7/7/2017    XXXOD   29.79
7/7/2017    XXXLC   64.57
7/7/2017    XXXLD   87.42
7/7/2017    XXXLF   53.96
7/7/2017    XXXUC   51.56
7/7/2017    XXXUD   52.88
7/7/2017    XXXUF   32.99
7/7/2017    XXXPC   63.83
7/7/2017    XXXPD   53.95
7/7/2017    XXXPF   49.25
7/7/2017    XXXWC   71.92
7/7/2017    XXXWD   62.96
7/7/2017    XXXWF   60.51
7/7/2017    XXXHC   66.12
7/7/2017    XXXHD   62.94
7/7/2017    XXXIC   66.46
7/7/2017    XXXID   52.26
7/7/2017    XXXJC   63.72
7/7/2017    XXXJD   25.85
7/7/2017    XXXQC   71.38
7/7/2017    XXXQD   54.01
7/14/2017   XXXKC   46.28
7/14/2017   XXXKD   71.42
7/14/2017   XXXMC   57.02
7/14/2017   XXXMD   38.24
7/14/2017   XXXTC   39.59
```

Like this i have for each server from Week ending 11/11/16 till last week of Jan'18. There are 25 Servers. i have to predict the forecast for all 25 servers for next 8 weeks. i have the following code which is forecasting for the next week
but its out put comes as the last week value for each server

Here is the code

```
input_data <- read.csv("input.csv", header= TRUE)
head(input_data)

library("forecast")
library("DBI")
library("RPostgreSQL")
library("lubridate")
Products = unique(input_data["Server.Name"][,])
output = matrix(0,nrow=(length(Products)*(1)),ncol=7)
colnames(output) =

  c(
    "Product",
    "DATE",
    "Forecast",
    "Lo_80",
    "Hi_80 ",
    "Lo_95",
    "Hi_95"
  )

for (i in Products) {

 train = head(input_data["PERCENT_USED"][input_data["Server.Name"]==i] , 90)

  train     = ts(train[1:(length(train))])

  fc1 = auto.arima(train)
  pred1 = forecast( fc1) 
  fit1_acry   = accuracy(pred1)
  fc2 = ets(train)  
  pred2 = forecast( fc2 )
  fit2_acry = accuracy(pred2 )

  MAPE = data.frame ( fit1_MAPE = fit1_acry[,'MAPE'], 
                       fit2_MAPE = fit2_acry[,'MAPE']
  )

  best =  which.min(MAPE)

  BestModel = get(paste('fc',best,sep="")) 

  forecastoutput = data.frame(forecast(BestModel, h=1)) 
  forecast_date = tail(input_data["DATE"][input_data["Server.Name"]==i],1)
  row_index = which(Products==i)

  output[row_index,1]   = i
  output[row_index,2]   = forecast_date
  output[row_index,3]   = (round(forecastoutput$Point.Forecast,2))
  output[row_index,4]   = as.numeric(round(forecastoutput$Lo.80,2))
  output[row_index,5]   = as.numeric(round(forecastoutput$Hi.80,2))
  output[row_index,6]   = as.numeric(round(forecastoutput$Lo.95,2))
  output[row_index,7] = as.numeric(round(forecastoutput$Hi.95,2))
  output_onestep = data.frame(output)

}
output_onestep
```

Help needed on how can i modify this for forecasting of 8 weeks

Comment: Please do not post an image of data, just post a form of the data that we can copy and paste into our own R session if necessary. It can be as simple as `dput(head(x))`, which will preserve all classes and types necessary.

Comment: BTW: I *think* your `train` is being assigned incorrectly. Shouldn't there be a comma after `[input_data["Server.Name"]==i,` to indicate row-selection?

Comment: You didn't post enough of your data for anyone to be able to tell if the forecast being the same as the last value is an issue or not (it is quite possible that that is the best that can be done). Aside from that, the `forecast` function has a parameter `h` that controls the forecast horizon.

Comment: @Chris Haug i have included the sample data for your reference

Comment: @r2evans i have added the sample data